# Regarding the sentence "J'ignore ce qu'il y a de vrai là-dedans"

Tags: sens

> Selon la légende, des spectres hantent les salles. J'ignore **ce qu**'il y a **de** vrai là-dedans, mais...

In this sentence, there are two things I cannot understand:

1. Why the need to say "j'ignore **ce que** {I don’t know **what**}" instead of "j'ignore **si** {I don’t know **if**}"?
2. I have read somewhere that in a question sentence or in a **si {if/whether}** clause, French does not make much distinction between "**any {de}**" and "**some {du}**". So why the need to say "**de** vrai" rather than "**du** vrai"? Is it equally correct to use "**du** vrai" in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here in "ce qu'il y a de vrai", **ce qu'** means basically "what is true and what is not" suggesting there might be some true stories and some that are merely fairy tales. Hence, there is a nuance you wouldn't get with a dichotomic if. (is the legend true or not)
2. As you are saying, there is actually a distinction between **de** and **du**. Interestingly here, **du** (some) would express the range of nuances that I explained in 1. ex. *Il y a du vrai là-dedans* would mean *there is some truth to it* but we already have that sense of a range thanks to **ce qu'**. On the other hand, **de** gives us the sense of a dichotomic judgement.

In terms of logical construction, you could say that:

- **ce qu'il** + **de** = in the substories of the legend, what is clearly true or false
  --> “J'ignore ce qu'il y a de vrai là-dedans”
- **ce qu'il** + **du** = in the substories of the legend, what is approximately true or false --> not working syntaxically

Note that “J'ignore **s'il** y a **du** vrai là-dedans” would bear a similar meaning as 
“J'ignore ce **qu'il** y a **de** vrai là-dedans”: "are some of the substories of the legends true?" vs. "Does the legend as a whole hold some truth?"